# How to integrate Restful Web Services with Struts 2

Tags: rest, struts2, jax-rs

How do you integrate or create a REST web-application??.I saw this plugin [struts-restplugin](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/rest-plugin.html) but the documentation does not provide any running example.can any one please provide some examples or reference tutorials about the same.

Comment: Integrate as in Struts 2 application being client ? provide some clarity

Comment: There's an entire showcase application.

Comment: can u please provide the link for that?

Comment: showcase application ships with struts-restplugin itself OR [here](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven2/org/apache/struts/struts2-rest-showcase/)

Comment: You should try the rest plugin documentation.  I've got good reason to believe those docs have improved quite a bit in the last few days . . .

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Are you referring to having a REST like "clean" URL structure or do you actually want to create a REST web-based API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Struts Restplugin [link](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/rest-plugin.html)

[Here](http://www.zulutown.com/blog/2009/01/28/rest-web-application-with-struts21-rest-and-convention-plugins/) helpful tutorial

Comment: here's an useful [link](http://www.slideshare.net/mrdon/an-introduction-to-struts-2-and-restful-applications-presentation)